# Pyspark Dataframe Default storagelevel for persist and cache()

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

P is a dataframe.
I observed below behaviour in storagelevel:

```
P.cache()
P.storageLevel
StorageLevel(True, True, False, True, 1)
P.unpersist()
P.StorageLevel
StorageLevel(False, False, False, False, 1)
P.persist()
StorageLevel(True, True, False, True, 1)
```

This shows default for persist and cache is MEM_DISk
BuT I have read in docs that Default for cache is MEM_ONLY
Pleasehelp me in understanding.

Comment: What version of Spark are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From PySpark documentation:

> Note The default storage level has changed to MEMORY_AND_DISK to match Scala in 2.0.

As you can find here: [Latest PySpark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.cache)

Comment: Using spark 2.4